# Creating, setting then using a variable within the same mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, variables

I'm trying to work with variables inside a mysql statement and struggling.

I've got this at the moment...

```
 SET @customer = 'UNKNOWN';
 SET @customer = (SELECT account FROM contacts WHERE emailaddy = 'myemailaddress' LIMIT 1);

 INSERT INTO cases
 (customer, details,severity,currentowner,created,createdautomatically)
 VALUES (@customer, 'This is a test case','SYS',now(),TRUE)
```

I'm getting 'Error. Parameter '@customer' must be defined'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT : After being told I was missing the declare, I've added this and I'm still getting the same error...

```
 DECLARE @customer VARCHAR(200);
 SET @customer = 'UNKNOWN';
 SET @customer = (SELECT account FROM contacts WHERE emailaddr = 'myemailaddress' LIMIT 1);

 INSERT INTO cases(customer, ....) VALUES (@customer, .....)

 Error. Parameter '@customer' must be defined..
```

ANOTHER EDIT....

Still doesnt seem to be working correctly :(

```
 DECLARE @customer VARCHAR(200);
 SET @customer := 'UNKNOWN';
 SET @customer := (SELECT account FROM contacts WHERE email = 'me');
 INSERT INTO cases (customer, ...) VALUES (@customer, '...')

 Error. Parameter '@customer' must be defined..
```

Comment: You need to have a `DECLARE @customer <datatype>` somewhere before you `SET` it.

Comment: More over in the `INSERT INTO` you have 6 columns defined but passing only 5 values for the same. Hope `severity`'s equivalent value is not passed.

Comment: Thanks Arulkumar... I've stripped alot of the real info out before posting to make sure I don't accidentally breach data protection :)

Comment: it is not an issue with declare please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with the 1st line

```
mysql> select "sss" into @customer;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO funding(dONATUR) VALUES (@customer);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM funding WHERE Donatur='sss';
+------+--------+---------+
| area | client | Donatur |
+------+--------+---------+
| NULL | NULL   | sss     |
+------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So what I'm trying to say there is 'if a result is found in contacts, make that the the value of @customer, else make the value 'UNKNOWN'.... does that make sense?

Comment: your issue is missing ":" value before = mark  i have added it for you SET @customer := (SELECT account FROM contacts WHERE emailaddr = 'myemailaddress' LIMIT 1);

Comment: See my latest edit Mahesh; It's not playing ball at all :(

Comment: sorry for the inconvenient due to previous answer

Comment: no worries Mahesh - thanks for taking the time to help! 
I'm struggling to use your example to successfully modify my code though.
should it be like this...
SELECT (SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE email = 'myaddress' LIMIT 1) into @customer;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116002/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with this query:

```
SELECT @customer := COALESCE(`account`, 'UNKNOWN') FROM `contacts` WHERE `emailaddr` = 'myemailaddress' LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `cases` (customer, ...) VALUES (@customer, '...');
```